# Exception value is not being caught in pytest.raises context manager

Tags: pytest

When I try to get the exception's value, this value is not asserted correctly.

```py
import pytest

class CustomException(Exception):
    """Custom Exception"""
    
    
def raise_custom_exception():
    raise CustomException("This is a test exception")

def test_custom_exception():
    with pytest.raises(CustomException) as execinfo:
        raise_custom_exception()
        assert execinfo == "This is not being caught"
```

I'm checking if the exception's value is the same of the expected value, but pytest show me all tests pass, even if the expected value of the exception is incorrect.

```sh
➜  stackoverflow_question pytest main.py
======================= test session starts ==========================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.7, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/israteneda/stackoverflow_question
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                               

main.py .                                                                                                                                                                [100%]

====================== 1 passed in 0.01s =============================
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pytest.raises` context manager is exited the moment an exception is raised - it only executes to the end if no exception was raised (and raises an assertion in this case). So, to check anything else after the raised exception, you have to do this outside the context manager:

```py
def test_custom_exception():
    with pytest.raises(CustomException) as execinfo:
        raise_custom_exception()
    assert execinfo == "This is being caught"
```

The `execinfo` is not part of the context manager scope (this is true for the context of any context manager), so it lives on after the context manager has exited, making this possible.

As mentioned by Matheus CAS in the comment, with current pytest versions you need to adapt the `assert` statement:

```py
    assert str(execinfo.value) == "This is being caught"
```

Comment: Great answer. Small nerding on the assert statement, this will always fail since types mismatching :-)

Comment: Ha, true. And I didn't find the duplicate...

Comment: Currently, you should do something like: 
`assert str(execinfo.value) == "This is being caught"`

Comment: @MatheusCAS - thanks, I adapted the answer. Just in case somebody finds this duplicate...